# How to access extended profile in django (1.9.4)

Tags: python, django

After following the documentation for [Extending the User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) i am unable to retrieve none of the profile fields.

in *users/models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    # Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete-models.CASCADE)

    is_good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

in *app/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'chooser.html')
```

in *app/templates/chooser.html*

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if user.is_good %}
<h1>Good Boy</h1>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

By All accounts it SHOULD work but does not.

After enabling debug i see that there is only a single sql request:
`SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id=8`

Django debug toolbar (Request Section) says

```
u'_auth_user_backend'
u'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend'
u'_auth_user_hash'
u'a72bee1aebbd30db244468ff794d7ef907c7d865'
u'_auth_user_id'
u'8'
```

Account exists in LDAP (and has been autosynced from it to the local DB of django). The profile has been manually edited to include the `is_good` boolean. Admin inlines work as expected.

What i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the profile of user while checking if user `is_good`

```
{% if user.profile.is_good %}
<h1>Good Boy</h1>
{% endif %}
```